# Loop da categoria Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loop

Estou tentando fazer um loop apenas da categoria que eu estiver no Wordpress e não estou conseguindo.
Alguém me dê um luz? estou tentando no arquivo **archive.php** do tema.

***Obs. Deverá exibir apenas os posts da categoria aberta.***

Abaixo o código do meu archive.php:

```
<?php
if (is_home()){
query_posts("showposts=5&cat=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12"); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="LatestPosts">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<div class="TxtNotice">
<?php //echo excerpt('20'); ?> <?php  echo the_title(); ?>[...]
</br>

</a>
</div>
<?php 
endwhile; wp_reset_query(); }?>
```

Comment: Tenta assim: `$query = new wp_query( array( 'cat' => '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12' ) );`

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback Fernando, mas no meu caso eu quero trazer apenas os posts da categoria que eu estiver.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o wordpress ele vai reconhecer o arquivo category.php por padrão para exibir os posts de uma categoria, basta colocar o seguinte código:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- DADOS DOS POSTS AQUI -->

<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

Após isso quando clicar em uma categoria o wordpress irá chamar essa página e já enviar a categoria como parâmetro para ela, exibindo assim os posts de uma determinada categoria.

Espero te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Felipe, o que você está procurando é 
get_queried_object();

Ele busca o objeto em questão.

Ou ainda, declarando a $post como global e retornando a categoria:

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

com isso você filtra seus posts apenas pela variável $postcat;

Vale ressaltar, que você pode sempre usar o var_dump() pra ficar ciente dos resultados.

Por exemplo, ao usar :

> global $post;
>   $postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );

Você pode dar um var_dump($postcat); E verificar o valor que retornou, se for o que você precisa, problema resolvido :)